# Cannot export component from module even if imported and declared Angular 8

Tags: modal-dialog, components, export, angular8

I am working on an app where I have a SharedUiModule containing all the components (and services) that will be used in other parts of the app.

Now I want to export from the SharedUiModule my ModalComponent (renamed PopupComponent) so I can reuse it in other modules by importing the SharedUiModule.

Problem is, in SharedUiModule, even after importing the PopupComponent and declaring it, when I want to export it I have the following alert : "Cannot export PopupComponent from SharedUiModule as it is neither declared nor imported in it". Spent few hours searching on the internet but couldn't find any similar issue.

My IDE is Intellij. Here is what my SharedUiModule looks like :

```
import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';
import {MatDialogModule, MatFormFieldModule, MatIconModule, MatListModule} from "@angular/material";
import {PopupComponent} from "./popup/popup.component";

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatDialogModule,
  ],
  declarations: [
    PopupComponent
  ],
  exports: [
    PopupComponent <= "Cannot export PopupComponent from SharedUiModule as it is neither declared nor imported in it"
  ],
  entryComponents: [PopupComponent]
})
export class SharedUiModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

A work mate told me to try to export the component the same way I imported the component and it works ! Now I don't understand why this way works while the exports properties should do the job (my work mate doesn't have any explanation too)

```
import {PopupComponent} from "./popup/popup.component";
export {PopupComponent};
```